# Search functionality with pagination on a website

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm developing a search functionality with pagination in my site to search for the product name and the brand name. I'm using this query to get the user's search request:

```
SELECT *
from products
WHERE name = 'optimum nutrition'
    OR brand = 'optimum nutrition' 
    OR name LIKE '%optimum%' 
    OR brand LIKE '%optimum%' 
    OR name LIKE '%nutrition%' 
    OR brand LIKE '%nutrition%'
```

I would like to display first the products that has the full 'optimum nutrition' in either the brand name and in the product name. How will I accomplish this?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your query should work fine, is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN (name = 'optimum nutrition' OR brand = 'optimum nutrition') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS full_match,
CASE WHEN (name LIKE '%optimum%' OR brand LIKE '%optimum%' OR name LIKE '%nutrition%' OR brand LIKE '%nutrition%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS half_match
FROM products 
WHERE (name = 'optimum nutrition' OR brand = 'optimum nutrition')
OR (name LIKE '%optimum%' OR brand LIKE '%optimum%' OR name LIKE '%nutrition%' OR brand LIKE '%nutrition%')
ORDER BY full_match, half_match
```

Answer (score 1):

First I believe `name = 'optimum nutrition'` will also be returned by `name LIKE '%optimum%'`.   this can work if you design a correct query. But `LIKE` is very slow and should be avoided, especially database is large. I just found this interesting [presentation which used October's Stackoverflow data and did full text searching](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql) on it. I think this comparison sheet is interesting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you look into 
[Zend Search Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html), to put search functionality on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [MySQL full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). This involves adding a `FULLTEXT` index on columns you want to search, and then using a query that will look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE MATCH(name, brand) AGAINST ('optimum')
```